# Default Firefox path for jpm doesn't work

Tags: javascript, firefox, ubuntu-16.04, jpm

I am running *Ubuntu 16.04* with *Firefox 46.0*. While trying to run *'jpm run'* on a new add-on (crawler) created with '*jpm init'*, I receive the following output:

```
JPM [info] Starting jpm run on Crawler
JPM [info] Creating a new profile
JPM [error] No Firefox binary found at null
JPM [error] Error: spawn /usr/lib64/firefox ENOENT
```

I couldn't figure out what was going on at first. I eventually run *'jpm run'* and noticed something: the path being used by *jpm run* was `/usr/lib64/firefox`. `/usr/lib64/firefox` is not where the *Firefox binary* is on *Ubuntu*;

I followed the [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm#Installation).

and read the [issues](https://github.com/mozilla-jetpack/jpm/issues/178) also but it is not helpful for it.

Comment: This is a question for Super User website, not for Stack Overflow. I vote to move it.

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software are off-topic** for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude i guess this quetion is related to the javascript extension developement because i face this issuse while developing this? So i posted here

Comment: Ok no problem. Let moderators make a decision. however seems that you solve the problem. Congrats :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *jpm* has an issue reported [here](https://github.com/mozilla-jetpack/jpm/issues/287). The default path for *firefox binary file* is `/usr/lib64/firefox`, but as per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_%28jpm%29) you have to use the:

```
jpm run -b /usr/bin/firefox
```

The location of binary file of *firefox* in *Ubuntu 16.04* is `/usr/bin/firefox`